# Producing Crosstab Query in php

Tags: php, crosstab

I would like to output this code onto a php page.

```
SET group_concat_max_len=5000;  
SET @sql = NULL;    

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(date = ''', date, ''', present, NULL)) AS ''',date, '''')) 
INTO @sql
FROM tblattendanceregister;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT employee, ', @sql, ' 
                    FROM tblattendanceregister 
                    GROUP BY employee');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

I have tried this so far:

```
<table border="0" name="attReportTable" id="attReportTable" class="table table-striped table-header-rotated">

<?php
$dySet=mysql_query("SET group_concat_max_len=5000;
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'MAX(IF(date = ''',
          date,
          ''', present, NULL)) AS ''',date, ''''
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM tblattendanceregister;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT employee, ', @sql, ' FROM tblattendanceregister GROUP BY  employee');
                                                PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;");

while($dy=mysql_fetch_array($dySet)){

?>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle"><div><?php echo $dy["employee"];?></div></td>
<td class="rotate-45"><div><span><?php echo date('d-M',strtotime($dy["date"]));?></span></div></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}

?>
</table>
```

I keep getting this error:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\cbmwdb\systemfiles\supchain\PersonnelPerformance.php on line 729.

Line 729 is where the while loop starts.

Comment: Have you tried to output this in PHP?  Please edit your question with the code that you've used to output this and the hold on this will be removed.  At this point, you've not provided any details that you've attempted this yourself.

Comment: You can't have multiple statements in a `mysql_query` call.

Comment: Is there a way I can correct this